# JAVA adding object to ArrayList of different Class,constantly replace 0 index and doesnt get bigger

Tags: java, arraylist, overwrite

I am trying to finish my home assignment for programming class, unfortunately getting stuck through half of it ,due to my stupidity. `ArrayList` that I have created overwrites `0` index constantly.

Here are my classes for creating invoices:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Order 
{
    private String customerName;
    private ArrayList<LineItem> items = new ArrayList<LineItem>();

    public Order(String customerName)
    {
        this.customerName = customerName;
    }

    public String getCustomerName()
    {
        return customerName;
    }

    public ArrayList<LineItem> getItems()
    {   
        return this.items;
    }

    public double getOrderTotal()
    {

        double totalOrder = items.get(0).getTotalPrice();
        return totalOrder;
    }

    public void addItem(String description,double unitPrice, int quantity)
    {
        LineItem object = new LineItem(description,unitPrice,quantity);
        items.add(object);
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        String.format("%n%-20s%-15s%-15f%-15f",items.get(0).getDescription(),
    items.get(0).getQuantity(),items.get(0).getUnitPrice(),getOrderTotal());

        return p;`                           

    }

}

public class LineItem
{
    private String description;
    private double unitPrice;
    private int quantity;

    public LineItem(String description,double unitPrice, int quantity)
    {
        this.description = description;
        this.unitPrice = unitPrice;
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }
    public String getDescription()
    {
        return this.description;
    }

    public double getUnitPrice()
    {
        return this.unitPrice;
    }

    public int getQuantity()
    {
        return this.quantity;
    }

    public double getTotalPrice()
    {
        return this.unitPrice * this.quantity;
    }
    public String toString()
    {
        return  String(this.description,this.unitPrice,this.quantity)     
    }
}
```

AND a part of ... while LOOP for main class

```
do
{

    customerName = AssignmentHelper.getRequiredStringInput("Please enterthe customer's name: ","A customer name must be entered!");

    newOrder = new Order(customerName);
    newOrder.addItem(description,unitPrice,quantity);

} while(Character.toString(userAnswer).equalsIgnoreCase ("Y"));
```

Answer (score 4):

Your loop creates a new `Order` object in each iteration :

```
newOrder = new Order(customerName);
```

Each `Order` object has a new empty `ArrayList`, which is why it seems the first index is always overwritten.

If you want a single `ArrayList` to hold all the items, you should create a single `Order` object prior to the do-while loop.

```
newOrder = new Order(customerName);
do {
    ...
    newOrder.addItem(description,unitPrice,quantity);
} while(Character.toString(userAnswer).equalsIgnoreCase ("Y"));
```

Comment: do you know how can i itirate through ArrayList insie the toString().Ideally i guess it suppose to override the TO String method from LineItem.

Comment: @DenysFiialko What exactly do you want to do? Print the contents of the ArrayList?

Comment: Program should display conents of Array using Order class with template from LineItem class.                                                                                                      Customer: Name

ORDER ITEMS
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Item Description                     000        00,000.00            000,000.00
{...}
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Answer (score 0):

In the loop, a new order object is created which has two fields (customer name and an Arraylist of line items). Initially the ArrayList will be empty.The call to addItem object creates a new Lineitem object and add its to the ArrayList items. Therefore the lineItem object will always be added to index zero.

Create a new object only when a new customer is added.You can have a HashMap where key is the customer name. If the key already exists add to the same object else create a new order object and it to the Map.

Comment: Thank you!!Appreciate fast response